How to use boto3 to find IOPS specs for AWS instance store volumes
I'm having trouble programmatically finding the IOPS specs for AWS instance store volumes, such as im4gn or m7gd.   Seems like it should probably be found in the ec2 describe_instance_types method, but it only returns the IOPS for the EBS volumes.   ChatGPT seems to think there is a section in that payload called InstanceStoreInfo but I can't find it anywhere in the docs.
Am I using the wrong components to find this info?
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2_client.describe_instance_types(InstanceTypes=['im4gn.4xlarge'])

It has some of the instance store info, but not the IOPS.

Rather than downvoting, how about explain what is unclear or low effort about my question?

That response includes the section:
            "InstanceStorageInfo": {
                "TotalSizeInGB": 7500,
                "Disks": [
                    {
                        "SizeInGB": 7500,
                        "Count": 1,
                        "Type": "ssd"
                    }
                ],
                "NvmeSupport": "required",
                "EncryptionSupport": "required"
            },

The Compute – Amazon EC2 Instance Types – AWS page lists im4gn.4xlarge as:

Instance Storage (GB): 1 x 7500 AWS Nitro SSD

There is no IOPS mentioned for instance store on that page either.
However, Specifications for Amazon EC2 storage optimized instances - Amazon EC2 lists "aggregated IOPS performance with 4,096 byte block size at queue depth saturation" as:

100% random read IOPS / Write IOPS: 250,000 / 200,000


Finding the specs is no problem, i just need to get at it via boto3 if possible.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ec2/latest/instancetypes/so.html
